# Windows 7 Repeating Logon/Logoff Process Sounds

Tags: windows-7

When I log off, log on, restart, shutdown, or power on, my Windows flashes the log off, log on, shutdown, or power on windows 7 screen and noises twice. So I hear two logon sounds, two logoff sounds, it looks like explorer is started twice (or restarted) as the taskbar flashes...

What is wrong with my computer?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I just ended up reinstalling windows after formatting my hard drive. The problem is fixed now.

Comment: Small crazy ghosts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm. First, have a look through **all** the enabled system sounds to see if any other event is playing the log on/whatever sounds. Painstaking process I know...

Next idea- disable the log on/whatever sounds from playing (change to "No sound") and see what effect that has. Does the sound still play once? Not at all? Let us know...

Comment: Well the sounds are just a result of something worse I think... Disabling the "exit windows" sound stops the sound, but the logoff screen still flashes. And when I log in after restarting, the log in screen flashes too.  I hope it doesn't have anything to do with my copy of windows being a student edition (meant only for upgrade), yet I made a bootable .iso out of it and did a clean install?